# How do I trigger rsync on file modification?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, rsync, vagrant

I can sync folders with `rsync -avz /directory /target`, now I wish to do it if I changed a file in `/directory` so `rsync` should be called automatically.

I am using Virtual Box and the shared folder of Virtual Box is really slow, especially if you have a webpage which is using the shared folder as document root. With `rsync` i would be able to work with my local files on shared folder and sync it automatically with document root.

I hope someone has an idea how to do so,`crontab` would be not good, because it is executed each x minutes, so if i don't do anything, it will still call `rsync` but not if I modified my file.

Best regards

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> crontab would be not good, cause it is executed each x seconds/minutes, so if i dont do anything, it will still call rsync but not if i modified my file

`rsync` will only sync the files that have been changed. If nothing has changed, it will exit. That's really a minimal overhead.

If you're unhappy with that you could use `inotifywait`:

```
while inotifywait -r /directory/*; do
    rsync -avz /directory /target
done
```

That will be more instant but it will do things *every* time you save.

Comment: well the problem it seems, that inotify is not able to check shared nfs folders. to make sure, what i want to,tryin to describe

i have virtual box installed with vagrant, there i have a shared folder "projects" it is mounted on boot, all my webserver files are located there so i can modify them on my host system(win7) 

as i told virtual box shared folders are really slow, so solution could be to sync the mounted nfs folder to another place e.g /var/www 

but the common ways are not working, i tryed fileschanged, icrontab, gues gamin or fam would help, but i dont know how to start or use them

Comment: @BlackScorp realistically you're stuck with just cronning rsync and letting it decide what needs syncing. As I lead with in the answer, that's not an awful bad option.

Comment: The other option is to push the files from the host rather than trying to detect changes remotely.

Comment: well this solution i used before, it has 2 problems:
1) i had to reconect everytime to my virtual box to edit files, which means, my virtual must running, quick editing is not working anymore
2) i dont know why, but because of the project scanning process of my IDE(Netbeans) samba shows 99% CPU Usage and everything within the virtual box is just slow while developing

i will try the rsyn + cronjob solution or the php build in webserver

Comment: The `inotifywait` solution has one slight but important drawback: it does not detect changes which happened when `rsync` is running. Consider the following situation: file A is changed; rsync is triggered; when rsync is *almost* done synchronizing file A, file B is changed. Now, `rsync` finished and `inotifywait` is running, but file B is **not synchronized** and won't be synchronized until some next change. **Consider using `lsyncd`** as suggested by @Arigion.

Comment: this will re-apply all events on all files after each change... and when it's applying it won't see any change in that period...

Answer (score 13):

You could use [Lsyncd (Live Syncing Daemon)](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd):

> Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface
>   (inotify or fsevents). It aggregates and combines events for a few
>   seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the
>   changes. By default this is rsync. Lsyncd is thus a light-weight live
>   mirror solution that is comparatively easy to install not requiring
>   new filesystems or block devices and does not hamper local filesystem
>   performance.

Here is for example a [tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=lsync).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `inotifywait` and `rsync`. `inotifywait` with the event `modify,create,delete` enabled. This way you will synchronize with your server only when the file changes, otherwise it will sync whenever a file is read (editors read several times your file to check if there are any changes). Thus said:

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete /directory; do
    rsync -avz /directory /target
done
```

Comment: This won't detect changes happened while rsync is running. Consider using `lsyncd` as suggested by @Arigion.

Comment: this will re-apply all events on all files after each change... and when it's applying it won't see any change in that period...

Answer (score 0):

Expanding slightly on a comment to the accepted answer I've had success using [fswatch](http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/) to trigger an `scp` of changed files to the guest.  On Linux this is a wrapper around `inotify` but it's also cross-platform (I'm on a Mac with an Arm-based QEMU guest). I've tacked on an `ssh` remote build as well.  The push approach works well with shares that behave in less than ideal ways.